# pytorch sort/median on GPU as slow as numpy on CPU. Am I missing something?

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to compute the median array out of a list of arrays. Here is the timing results of a short exercise. I have an NVIDIA Quadro P2000 GPU, and have verified with FFTs and convolutions that cuda/torch runs 100's of times faster than numpy. However, when it comes to sorting, the GPU is fairly "stuck" and isn't giving me much meaningful acceleration.

```
import numpy as np
import torch as th
c=np.random.rand(3,480,700).astype(np.float32) # cpu version
g=th.tensor(c).to(device='cuda:0')             # gpu version
%timeit np.median(c,axis=0)        # 14.3 ms ± 61.6 µs per loop 
%timeit np.sort(c,axis=0)[1]       # 9.59 ms ± 26.5 µs per loop
%timeit th.median(g,dim=0).values  # 11.8 ms ± 9.13 µs per loop
%timeit th.sort(g,dim=0).values[1] # 9.28 ms ± 6.01 µs per loop
```

I have verified with nvidia-smi that the GPU is running during the torch calls, fwiw.

There are plenty of reports (like [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/surprising-sorting-tips-for-data-scientists-9c360776d7e)) that show torch's sorting algorithm beating the pants off of numpy, but I'm not getting it to happen. Anyone know whether there is a simple trick to make the torch sort/median on the GPU work faster?

Comment: Your `g` tensor is created from `x`. When I replace it with `c` I get results that show the PyTorch implementation outperforming numpy: https://i.imgur.com/5yB7vO1.png

Comment: Yeah that was just a type-o. I fixed it. The timings are correct, I had just changed variable names from my notebook to here.

Answer (score 0):

What is `x`?

Maybe you mis-placed it? Because it makes sense if it is `c` instead.

Also, as @JoshVarty stated, the pyTorch implementation outperforms numpy when you change it to `x`.

So, your code should be :

```
import numpy as np
import torch as th
c=np.random.rand(3,480,700).astype(np.float32) # cpu version
g=th.tensor(c).to(device='cuda:0')             # gpu version
%timeit np.median(c,axis=0)        
%timeit np.sort(c,axis=0)[1]      
%timeit th.median(g,dim=0).values 
%timeit th.sort(g,dim=0).values[1]
```

Comment: I did type that one character wrong on accident. Fixed it a few min ago. I'm glad people are seeing an acceleration on their GPU. I'm not, but maybe that is just because mine is a low-performance laptop version.

Comment: Hmm lets do a small exercise then. Try checking your allocated memory and cached memory. For torch, it can be seen as `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()` and `torch.cuda.memory_cached()` @AstroBen

Comment: `th.cuda.memory_allocated(), th.cuda.memory_cached()` yields
`(387008512, 557842432)`

Comment: @AstroBen well that means there is some memory cached, which we can free. Free that memory by using `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`. Run the earlier two commands again, you should have less memory allocated / cached. Then maybe you will be able to run your code and see a performance increase.